# Playing with Vagrant and python recipe and I do not figure how I can use python_virtualenv

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe, chef-solo

My Vagrantfile looks like this (some parts are missing):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|    
    # Provisioning
    config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
        chef.cookbooks_path = ["provisioning/chef/cookbooks"]
        chef.log_level = :debug
        chef.run_list = ["recipe[python]"]
    end
end
```

According to [Opscode python recipe Readme](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/python), it is possible to install python package with a `python_pip` command and python virtualenvs with a `python_virtualenv` command.
How Can I integrate them in my `Vagrantfile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pip` and `virtualenv` are already included as part of python's `default` recipe. By specifying `recipe[python]` you effectively loaded recipe `recipe[python::default]` which [includes](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/python/blob/master/recipes/default.rb) respective install method, pip and virtualenv.

In order to use `python_pip` and `python_virtualenv` providers (as name suggest they provide the functionality) you just add them to your custom application recipe like suggested in cookbook's README file

```
python_pip "gunicorn"

python_virtualenv "/home/ubuntu/my_cool_ve" do
  owner "ubuntu"
  group "ubuntu"
  action :create
end
```

you need to create own cookbook/recipe. I would recommend to first understand the logic of the cookbooks, but if you want a kick start you can use something like

```
cd to/your/cookbooks/directory
mkdir mycookbook
cd mycookbook
mkdir recipes
touch README.md
cat >recipes/default.rb <<-EOF
# create sample directory
directory "/tmp/xx"

python_pip "gunicorn"

python_virtualenv "/home/ubuntu/my_cool_ve" do
  owner "ubuntu"
  group "ubuntu"
  action :create
end

EOF
```

and add this cookbook to run list `recipe[mycookbook]`.

```
    chef.run_list = ["recipe[python]", "recipe[mycookbook]"]
```

Don't forget to check resources like [Cookbooks](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbooks.html) and [Getting started with Chef](http://gettingstartedwithchef.com/)